# Close button on a frame not working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, file-io, event-dispatch-thread

I wrote a GUI program, when the program is running(write file), close button is not     working, so I cant stop it when it's running. Anybody know why? And can i stop it(when it's writting file)?

Comment: Can you include some of your code to be able to analyse?

Comment: Sounds like you have either set `JFrame#setDefaultCloseOperation` to `DO_NOTHING` OR there is a blocking I/O, loop or other operation, preventing the Event Dispatching Thread from processing the close event request - like *"when it's writting file"*

Comment: Hi @MadProgrammer,I've set JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: Hi @cworner1,my code has nothing special. it starts to write file when i hit start button. But when it's writting,it can be stop

Comment: @MadProgrammer I got you,so I have to change my code to mutil thread?

Comment: @TheRealBo Yes, but, be very careful, Swing is NOT thread safe.  You can only update the UI from the EDT.  Check the linked tutorial, it shows how you might be able to cancel the `SwingWorker`

Comment: Sorry, my psychic programmer skills arn't working right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without further evidence, I guess you are writing out your file in the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

This is very, very bad.  The EDT is responsible for (amongst other things) processing all the UI events that occur, including the request to close your window.  But if you block this thread with time consuming tasks (like I/O, loops, `Thread#sleep` or any other blocking operation), then the EDT is unable to process any of the events accumulating in the queue.

In this case, you best bet would be to use a `SwingWorker` to off load the writing of the file to another thread.  Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information

Comment: ahh,i will check it later,let me show you my code that just changed
<code>
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    try {
     Test window = new Test();
     window.frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });
</code>

Comment: thx @MadProgrammer,seems a good answer.sorry for my repuatation is too low to vote ur answer up